# How to bind data from a datatable into a select box

Tags: asp.net

I found demo of 
[Dual Listbox jQuery Plug-in](http://www.meadmiracle.com/dlb/DLBDocumentation.aspx)
But I don't know how can I bind data from a datatable into a select box. Can you help me, please!

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.Net select boxes are called DropDownLists.
They can be populated like this:

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = dataTableVariable;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "DisplayValueColumnName";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "DataValueColumnName";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Actually, there's a ListBox ASP.NET control... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm using "Dual listbox jQuery Plug-in" It's a HTML select box, not a DropDownList:
<select id="countries" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="countries[]">
</select>

Comment: Change the DropDownList to ListBox.
ASP.Net actually renders a <select>.
Binding the data works the same.
If you want better control, use a repeater with <select> in the header, </select> in the footer, and your <option>s in the template/body.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `runat="server"` attribute to the HTML select tag:

```
<select id="lbOptions" multiple="true" name="lbOptions" runat="server"></select>
```

Note, Visual Studio will probably complain about the `multiple="true"` attribute, but if you don't set it to "true", the page will fail.

In your code-behind, do this:

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

...

public partial class YourForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected HtmlSelect lbOptions;

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Adding five elements for demonstrations sake...
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      lbOptions.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item " + i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
    }
  }
}
```

That's it: Output on your page should look like this now:

```
<select name="lbOptions" id="lbOptions" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="0">Item 0</option>
  <option value="1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="3">Item 3</option>
  <option value="4">Item 4</option>
</select>
```

Note how ASP.NET changed the "true" value back to the correct "multiple".